# in angularjs, options for select in different controller - how to refresh?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

have two different controllers, one for language, `langCntl`, and one for words, `wordCntl`.

in the `wordCntl` record there is an attribute called `ln`.  `ln` is displayed in the form using `ng-select`, with `ngOptions` based on records in the `langCntl` controller.

how do I make the `select` for `ln` refresh in `wordCntl` when records change in `langCntl`?

#### langMod.js

```
var langMod = angular.module('langMod', ['ngResource']);

langMod.controller('langCntl',function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.langs = [];
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $http.get( '/lang.jsn').success( function(data) {
      console.log( 'http.success: data='+data );
      $scope.langs = angular.copy($scope.origs);
    });
  };
  $scope.reset();
});

langMod.controller('wordCntl',function($scope) {
  var langElem = document.querySelector("[ng-controller='langCntl']");
  $scope.langs = angular.element(langElem)).scope().langs;
  $scope.rcd = { ln: 'en', word: '?' };
});
```

#### index.html

```
<html lang='en' ng-app='langMod' >
<body>
  <ng-form ngForm='abc' ng-controller='wordCntl' >
    <select ng-model="rcd.ln" ng-options="c.lang as c.name for c in langs">
  </ng-form>
</body>
</html>
```

What interesting (to me):

1. after `langCntl.langs` changes, `wordCntl.langs` remains an empty array.
2. in the `ngoptions`, is there a way to directly use the records in `langCntl`?

Answer (score 2):

Reference angualrjs sdk:
[$broadcast(name, args)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope)

> Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on listeners.
>
> The event life cycle starts at the scope on which $broadcast was called. All listeners listening for name event on this scope get notified. Afterwards, the event propagates to all direct and indirect scopes of the current scope and calls all registered listeners along the way. The event cannot be canceled.

Comment: if you post something from doc , wrap it with '>' to show that its not your words

Comment: that's cool, but what about the nitty gritty of getting the `select` to refresh?

Comment: you can add a ng-change event lisentner to you select element.